# Power App that lets users search for items containing word "urgent" in the title

Tags: powerapp, large-lists

I have a list with 2 million items. I need to build Power App that lets users search for the items containing word "urgent" in the title. The word urgent can appear anywhere in the title.

Is it possible to do or Power Apps can't handle a task like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given it is 2 million items, I would not recommend using SharePoint Lists to store that many items. It would cause a lot of problems and limitations in your data (presentation/manipulation). It still better to store it in SQL and create the presentation layer in SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is not possible with such large list, PowerApps is a bad tool for that.